# How do i join more than 2 postgres tables and get the result as nestedjson in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, nested

```
select categories.*, array_agg(questions.r_question) as theQuestions from categories
inner join
    (select questions.*, json_build_object('question', questions.question) as r_question,
            array_agg(answers.ans) as answeeer from questions)
        questions on categories.category_id = questions.category_id
inner join
    (select answers.*, json_build_object('answer', answers.answer) as ans from answers)
        answers on questions.question_id = answers.question_id
group by categories.category_id;
```

I want to have an array of Categories that embedded questions and questions embedded answers

tables structure

```html
<pre>


quizx=# select * from categories
quizx-# ;
 category_id |       title       |          description
-------------+-------------------+--------------------------------
           1 | Computer scicence | Quiz based on computer science
           2 | General culture   | Quiz based on general reality
           3 | Chemistry         | Quiz based on chemistry and so
           8 | Capstone          | Quiz based on chemistry and so
(4 rows)


quizx=# select * from answers;
 answer_id |          answer          | correct | question_id
-----------+--------------------------+---------+-------------
         1 | Instructions             |       0 |           1
         7 | Line length and wrapping |       0 |           2
         8 | Control Structure        |       1 |           2
         4 | All of the above         |       1 |           1
         6 | Functions                |       0 |           2
         5 | Comments                 |       0 |           2
         3 | Documents                |       0 |           1
         2 | Data Structures          |       0 |           1
        14 | cool stuff               |       0 |           2
(9 rows)


quizx=# select * from questions;
 question_id |                                                    question                                                    | category_id
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------
           1 | Software is defined as ____                                                                                    |           1
           2 | The rules of writing 'if-then-else', 'case-switch', 'while-until' and 'for' control flow statements are called |           1
           4 | Who is it??                                                                                                    |           1
           5 | slam                                                                                                           |           2
           6 | Is it good???                                                                                                  |           2
           7 | test                                                                                                           |           2
           8 | again                                                                                                          |           2
(7 rows)

</pre>
```

Expected result from my query:

```html
<pre>

[
    {
        "categoryId": 1,
        "theCategory": "computer science ",
        "description": "stuff about code\r\n",
        "questions": [
            {
                "questionId": 9,
                "theQuestion": "what year was the video game crash?",
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "answerId": 22,
                        "theAnswer": "1985",
                        "correctAnswer": false
                    },
                    {
                        "answerId": 23,
                        "theAnswer": "1994",
                        "correctAnswer": false
                    },
                    {
                        "answerId": 24,
                        "theAnswer": "1983",
                        "correctAnswer": true
                    },
                    {
                        "answerId": 25,
                        "theAnswer": "1977",
                        "correctAnswer": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "questionId": 11,
                "theQuestion": "what language was the first commercially available?",
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "answerId": 30,
                        "theAnswer": "java script",
                        "correctAnswer": false
                    },
                    {
                        "answerId": 31,
                        "theAnswer": "C",
                        "correctAnswer": false
                    },
                    {
                        "answerId": 32,
                        "theAnswer": "FORTRAN",
                        "correctAnswer": true
                    },
                    {
                        "answerId": 33,
                        "theAnswer": "ada",
                        "correctAnswer": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "questionId": 12,
                "theQuestion": "what is COBAL?",
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "answerId": 34,
                        "theAnswer": "a business language used in many  machines  ",
                        "correctAnswer": true
                    },
                    {
                        "answerId": 35,
                        "theAnswer": "the first mainframe ",
                        "correctAnswer": false
                    },
                    {
                        "answerId": 36,
                        "theAnswer": "the first computer introduced ",
                        "correctAnswer": false
                    },
                    {
                        "answerId": 37,
                        "theAnswer": "the computer that introduced arpnet to the us military ",
                        "correctAnswer": false
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "categoryId": 4,
        "theCategory": "video games ",
        "description": "this is about video games \r\n",
        "questions": [
            {
                "questionId": 10,
                "theQuestion": "what game was the iconic character Mario's first appearance?",
                "answers": [
                    {
                        "answerId": 26,
                        "theAnswer": "donkey kong ",
                        "correctAnswer": true
                    },
                    {
                        "answerId": 27,
                        "theAnswer": "super mario bros ",
                        "correctAnswer": false
                    },
                    {
                        "answerId": 28,
                        "theAnswer": "mario bros",
                        "correctAnswer": false
                    },
                    {
                        "answerId": 29,
                        "theAnswer": "donkey kong country",
                        "correctAnswer": false
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

<pre>
```

I am getting the following error:
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "answers"
LINE 7:             array_agg(answers.ans) as answeeer from question...
                              ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 212

Comment: Could I suggest you give details about what tables you have, and an example of what end result you're looking for?

Comment: I have edited my post sir, so you can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by aggregating the answers for each question, then aggregating the questions for each category, then aggregating those into a single object.  You can just use a common table expression to achieve this.

For example:

```
WITH q AS (
  SELECT
    category_id,
    to_jsonb(q) ||
      jsonb_build_object('answers', jsonb_agg(a)) qs
  FROM
    questions q
  LEFT JOIN
    answers a ON q.question_id = a.question_id
  GROUP BY
    q.category_id, q
),
c AS (
  SELECT
    to_jsonb(c) ||
      jsonb_build_object('questions', jsonb_agg(q.qs)) cs
  FROM
    categories c 
  LEFT JOIN
    q ON c.category_id = q.category_id
  GROUP BY
    c
)
SELECT
  jsonb_pretty(jsonb_agg(c.cs))
FROM
  c;
```